# Hyperledger fabric multihost setup for first-network example

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup first-network example on a Multihost environment using docker swarm with below configuration to begin with:

HOST1

- Orderer
- Org1-pee0
- Org1-peer1
- CLI

HOST2

- Org2-pee0
- Org2-pee1

I have only changed the docker-compose-cli.yaml to make it compatible with swarm(code given below). **I am not able to add the Host2 / Org2 peers to channel**.

Executing the below steps in order:

- byfn -m generate
- docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-cli.yaml overnet
- Enter the CLI docker and execute ./scripts/script.sh mychannel

I keep getting the below error

> **2017-08-15 02:42:49.512 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 006 Obtaining default signing identity
>
>   Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer**
>
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/common.go:116 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.GetEndorserClient
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/channel.go:149 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.InitCmdFactory
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:138 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.join
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:42 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.joinCmd.func1
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:599 
>  github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 
>  github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC 
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 
>  github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute 
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:118 main.main 
>   /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main 
>   /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit 
>   **Caused by: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.org1.example.com, peer0, not peer0.org2.example.com**

docker-compose-cli.yaml

Orderer

```
version: '3'
networks:
  overnet:

services:

  orderer_example_com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
#      - 7049:7049
    networks:
      - overnet
    deploy:
       replicas: 1
       placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Org1 Peers

```
  peer0_org1_example_com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=overnet
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    networks:
      - overnet
    deploy:
       replicas: 1
       placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Org2 Peers

```
  peer0_org2_example_com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=overnet
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    networks:
      - overnet
    deploy:
       mode: replicated
       replicas: 1
       placement:
          constraints: [node.role == worker]
```

CLI

```
  cli:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
#    command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer_example_com
      - peer0_org1_example_com
      - peer1_org1_example_com
      - peer0_org2_example_com
      - peer1_org2_example_com
    networks:
      - overnet
    deploy:
       replicas: 1
       placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

**crypto-config.yaml (Did not make any changes this file, however attaching here for reference)**

```
OrdererOrgs:
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------ 

  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
# configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
#
# Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
#   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
#   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
#                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
#
#                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
#
#                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
#                 Org.Domain, respectively.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specs:
#   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org2.example.com"
#     CommonName: foo27.org5.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
#   - Hostname: bar
#   - Hostname: baz
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "Template"
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
# from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
# You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
# or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
#
# Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
# sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
# name collisions
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Template:
  Count: 2
  # Start: 5
  # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "Users"
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Users:
  Count: 1
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Comment: Can you please paste a gist or pastebin of your crypto-config.yaml that was used to generate the certificates using cryptogen?

Comment: @christo4ferris I have added the crypto-config.yaml file here, however I did not make any changes to this file, I am using the original file provided in the example codebase of first-network

Comment: and you did not change the script.sh either?

Comment: Yes, I didn't change script.sh either. Also here I have share the configuration for only peer0 of both the orgs, however I am using peer1 too, I wanted to save the space here that's why I only pasted the peer0 config values here.

Comment: what is this config in the CLI container?       - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt

Comment: I was trying to use different orgnames for testing, however I have used the correct value as peer0.org2.example.com in my application, apologies for pasting the wrong value here. It is pointing to the right peer and org combination cert file, Have also checked the script.sh file where the values are set before joining the peers to channel.

Comment: @christo4ferris did you get a chance to look into it, thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Well, I really cannot reproduce because you have not shared exactly what you used. The issue is that the certificate that the MSP found for signing a proposal is incorrect for the organization. This suggests to me that somehow you have moved things around incorrectly and the certificate for peer0.org2.example.com is actually for peer0.org1.example.com.

Comment: I have searched around and only found single org examples in swarm mode. I am guessing adding Org2 adds more complexity and this is the only query in stackoverflow on Org2 with Swarm

Answer (score 2):

I was able to host hyperledger fabric network on multiple machines using docker swarm mode. Swarm mode provides a network across multiple hosts/machines for the communication of the fabric network components.

This post explains the deployment process.It creates a swarm network and all the other machines join the network. https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

Comment: I have searched around and only found single org examples in swarm mode. I am guessing adding Org2 adds more complexity and this is the only query in stackoverflow on Org2 with Swarm

Answer (score 1):

I have set up the mutlihost setup of fabric network. My orderer and one peer is on one host and one peer is on 2nd host. For this we need to make changed in configtx.yml file for orderer section:

```
Profiles:
    CommonOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortiumJA:
                Organizations:
                    - *test
                    - *mch
                    - *test2
                    - *test3
    CommonOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortiumJA
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *test
                - *mch
                - *test2
                - *test3    
    MJAOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortiumJA:
                Organizations:
                    - *test
                    - *mch
                    - *test2
    MJAOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortiumJA
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *test
                - *mch
                - *test2
    MABOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortiumAB:
                Organizations:
                    - *test2
                    - *mch
                    - *test3
    MABOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortiumAB
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *test
                - *mch
                - *test3
    MBJOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortiumBJ:
                Organizations:
                    - *test3
                    - *mch
                    - *test
    MBJOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortiumBJ
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *test3
                - *mch
                - *test


Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg

        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/mch.test/msp

    - &test
          Name: test

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: testMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/test.test/msp

        AnchorPeers:

            - Host: peer0.test.test
              Port: 7054
    - &airtel
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: airtel

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: test2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/test2.test/msp

        Anc
            - Host: peer0.test2.test
              Port: 7055
    - &bsnl
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: test3

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: test3MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/test3.test/msp

        AnchorPeers:
                 - Host: peer0.test3.test
              Port: 7059
    - &mch

        Name: mch

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: mchMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/mch.test/msp

        AnchorPeers:
             - Host: peer0.mch.test
              Port: 7051          

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - 10.64.253.213:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        MaxMessageCount: 10


        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB


        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:

        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092


    Organizations:


Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:

===============================================================


after this pull up the orderer and peer1 on one server and peer2 on different server. Create channel using IP of orderer instead of name then copy the channel file to other peer also and join both peers one at a time. Install chaincode on two peers. You are good to go.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Docker-swarm to implement MultiHost Hyperledger fabric Blockchain Network.
Read the steps from the Following URL.

https://github.com/chudsonsolomon/Block-chain-Swarm-Multi-Host

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you don't have to

> Enter the CLI docker and execute ./scripts/script.sh mychannel

Or have you commented the docker compose file like is described in the "[Start the network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#start-the-network)" step?

On the other hand, I tell you that I have achieved to setting up a Multihost environment using docker. However, instead of defining the network overlay, I defined the `network_mode: host` for all the docker containers that I'm going to start up.

Could you show the logs that are appearing in the Peer and in the Orderer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem came from the service name of docker-compose:

- orderer_example_com => **orderer.example.com**
- peer0_org1_example_com => **peer0.org1.example.com**
- ...

**Let use dot (.) not underscore (_) for naming**.
[Read wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) for more

You also need docker-swarm for multiple host setup